# Picking Up a link of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was just learning how to develop a link sharing system and came across a road block.I wanted to pick up the link of the current webpage opened in my browser. For eg if i am on "google.com" the it should pick up the link of it.
Also i wanted this link to be pasted in a input box that was designed by me so that i can notify the user as to on which page he is at the current moment.
I tried the OmniBox of Google to pick up the address but was not able to write a robust function for it in JavaScript.

Comment: Well i have tried it in a manifest file using the omnibox for chrome extension but i was not able to develop a function for picking up a link.I am a first time developer so not very familiar to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get it in your JS code, should be able to get the current url with:

```
   var url = document.URL;
   var elem = document.getElementById("myinputbox");
   elem.value = url;
```

You could do the get/set in one line if you wanted to:

```
document.getElementById("myinputbox").value = url;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more. and how do i paste my link in the input box of my page?

Comment: Elaborated, does that answer your question?

Comment: Just one more thing.Is the "myinputbox" the name the Input box.

Comment: No, it is the id. Note I used "getElementById", emphasis placed on Id at the end there.

Comment: This is my WebPage which will recieve the URL

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h1> 
 LinkLet
</h1>
Email the Link <input type="text" name="myinputbox" class="form1" id="myinputbox"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This is my JS Page

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "Link.html";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
 var url = document.URL;
   var elem = document.getElementById("myinputbox");
   elem.value = url;

Comment: Firstly please don't just paste random snippets of code and ask if its going to work, like you just did, try it for yourself and then ask questions. Straight after you do this "var url = document.URL;", have you tried doing "alert(url);" to see if the value is correct or if your js even gets that far. The code is 100%.

Comment: Well i apologize as i am new to this forum and language so i dint know that. Please excuse me.